ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS after migrating to Spring security 6 with jsp
I am migrating my project to Spring boot 3. It has jsp pages configured. The problem is when running with Spring security 6, the pages are not loading any more with the error ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS on browser
I got a lot of debug logs, but all are same:
2024-06-27T10:24:47.982+02:00 DEBUG 55771 --- [jsp] [0.1-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'login', model {}
2024-06-27T10:24:47.983+02:00 DEBUG 55771 --- [jsp] [0.1-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp]
2024-06-27T10:24:47.984+02:00 DEBUG 55771 --- [jsp] [0.1-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'login', model {}
2024-06-27T10:24:47.984+02:00 DEBUG 55771 --- [jsp] [0.1-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp]

My security config file
src/main/java/org/example/jsp/WebSecurityConfig.java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http

                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth
                        .requestMatchers("/login").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(form -> form.loginPage("/login")
                                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                );
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        UserDetails user =
            User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("user")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();

        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }
}

src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Login</h1>
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/login" method="post">
    <div>
        <label for="username">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
    <c:if test="${param.error != null}">
        <div>Invalid username or password.</div>
    </c:if>
</form>
</body>
</html>

src/main/java/org/example/jsp/JspController.java
@Controller
public class JspController {

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String getLogin() {
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "home";
    }
}

And dependencies in pox.xml
<properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSP dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
<!--            <version>2.0.0</version>-->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Server dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

I have used Spring boot 3.2.7
application properties (src/main/resources/application.properties) file contains
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

Also tried by adding
src/main/java/org/example/jsp/WebMvcConfig.java:
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }
}

I am not getting what am I doing wrong. Please guide me to fix this problem, Thanks a lot. :)
Update:
Here are the logs:
2024-06-28T14:02:41.048+02:00 DEBUG 77220 --- [jsp] [.1-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2024-06-28T14:02:41.048+02:00 DEBUG 77220 --- [jsp] [.1-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2024-06-28T14:02:41.048+02:00 DEBUG 77220 --- [jsp] [.1-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
2024-06-28T14:02:41.048+02:00 DEBUG 77220 --- [jsp] [.1-8080-exec-10] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.example.jsp.JspController#getLogin()
2024-06-28T14:02:41.048+02:00 DEBUG 77220 --- [jsp] [.1-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
2024-06-28T14:02:41.048+02:00 DEBUG 77220 --- [jsp] [.1-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'login', model {}
2024-06-28T14:02:41.048+02:00 DEBUG 77220 --- [jsp] [.1-8080-exec-10] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp]
2024-06-28T14:02:41.048+02:00 DEBUG 77220 --- [jsp] [.1-8080-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp
2024-06-28T14:02:41.048+02:00 DEBUG 77220 --- [jsp] [.1-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to anonymous SecurityContext
2024-06-28T14:02:41.049+02:00 DEBUG 77220 --- [jsp] [.1-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.w.s.HttpSessionRequestCache        : Saved request http://localhost:8080/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp?continue to session
2024-06-28T14:02:41.049+02:00 DEBUG 77220 --- [jsp] [.1-8080-exec-10] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to http://localhost:8080/login
2024-06-28T14:02:41.049+02:00 DEBUG 77220 --- [jsp] [.1-8080-exec-10] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/].[jsp]        : The response class [class org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterResponse] could not be unwraped to the Catalina response class and will be closed immediately after the forward
2024-06-28T14:02:41.049+02:00 DEBUG 77220 --- [jsp] [.1-8080-exec-10] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 302 FOUND

Then to solve the redirect issue I added WEB-INF in permitAll in security config
.requestMatchers("/login", "/error", "/webjars/**", "/css/**", "/WEB-INF/**").permitAll()

And the now new error is
2024-06-28T14:04:54.841+02:00 DEBUG 77243 --- [jsp] [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /login
2024-06-28T14:04:54.848+02:00 DEBUG 77243 --- [jsp] [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /login
2024-06-28T14:04:54.849+02:00 DEBUG 77243 --- [jsp] [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/login", parameters={}
2024-06-28T14:04:54.850+02:00 DEBUG 77243 --- [jsp] [0.1-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.example.jsp.JspController#getLogin()
2024-06-28T14:04:54.857+02:00 DEBUG 77243 --- [jsp] [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7]
2024-06-28T14:04:54.857+02:00 DEBUG 77243 --- [jsp] [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'login', model {}
2024-06-28T14:04:54.858+02:00 DEBUG 77243 --- [jsp] [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp]
2024-06-28T14:04:54.860+02:00 DEBUG 77243 --- [jsp] [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp
2024-06-28T14:04:54.862+02:00 DEBUG 77243 --- [jsp] [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp
2024-06-28T14:04:54.906+02:00 ERROR 77243 --- [jsp] [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/].[jsp]        : Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.ConditionalTagSupport
.
.
.
2024-06-28T14:04:54.908+02:00 DEBUG 77243 --- [jsp] [0.1-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Error rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView: name 'login'; URL [/WEB-INF/jsp/login.jsp]]


My JSP pages were authenticated as well so I added in permitAll, helped me to fix the issue also disabled the csrf for now
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                        .requestMatchers( "/webjars/**", "/WEB-INF/**").permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(formLogin -> formLogin
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .logout(logout -> logout
                        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                        .permitAll()
                )
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        return http.build();
    }

In addition, I was using wrong dependency,
<dependency>
     <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
     <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

instead should be using
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>

